# your account is temporarily disabled

Tags: customer-account, administration

Good evening.
I inherit a Magento from my webmster that can no longer deal with it.
I know little about programming, but I can do something about it.
For several days I would like to enter the admin but I will return this string

> "You have not signed in correctly or your account is temporarily
>   disabled"

Someone can help me ? I have access to the database via phpmyadmin

Thanks in advance !

---

Buona sera.
Eredito un Magento dal mio webmster che non può più occuparsene.
So poco di programmazione, ma qualcosa riesco a farlo.
Da diversi giorni vorrei entrare in admin ma mi restituisce questa stringa

> "Non hai eseguito l'accesso correttamente o il tuo account è
>   temporaneamente disattivato"

Qualcuno potrebbe aiutarmi.Ho l'accesso al database mediante il phpmyadmin
Grazie in anticipo !

Comment: Magento version?

Comment: I think Magento2

Comment: do you have terminal access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way to release lock from myslq/phpmyadmin

Select database and run below mentioned query make sure replace `adminusername` with your admin user name. Also check if there is any table prefix add it before table `admin_user` so it should be look like `tableprefix_admin_user`

```
UPDATE `admin_user` set lock_expires=NULL,first_failure=NULL,failures_num=0 where username="adminusername"
```

2nd option from CLI

you can unlock admin user via terminal/ssh/CLI by running below mentioned command from magento root. Make sure replace `adminusername` with your admin user name.

```
php bin/magento admin:user:unlock adminusername
```

Comment: Before doing the recommended actions I would like to clear the cache. Can you tell me how can I do? thank you very much for your help

Comment: Ahh sorry for the late reply there is no easy way to clear cache from out side however if you have cpanel you can remove folder `cache` in `var` directory

Comment: You're very kind. Now I try. I'll let you know

Comment: If its work please mark answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark and upvote it if answer helped you

Comment: Forgive me yesterday I could not continue working. Now I ask you I have to delete the cache folder or just its contents

Comment: just delete content inside

Comment: it is possible that the folder is 15000 files

Comment: which cache directory you are clearing drop path here or screen shot

Comment: Ok ok ...It was a success
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

welcome to Magento SE.

Make sure you put the proper credentials in order to access the account. If you are sure, there can be an option that the person which gave you the credentials are wrong.

If you have SSH access, you can create a user in order to log in to the admin panel using this command:

> php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user='new-admin'
>   --admin-password='!admin123!' --admin-email='info@domain.com' --admin-firstname='Jon' --admin-lastname='Doe'

Comment: i don't know :-(

Answer (score 0):

[image]

ftp - /public_html/var/cache  >> image required Aman Alam

Comment: correct need to delete content inside cache but deleting it from ftp will take to long time you much need cPanel on directly clear cache from CLI by applying command `php bin/magento cache:clean`

Comment: Hi  Aman Alam sorry for my absence.
I deleted the cache var/cache via FTP
I do not have CLI access 
Now  I proceed to update passwords

Comment: You can you can clear lock of your admin user from phpmyadmin by running below mentioned query

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Aman Alam .... Is this where I have to run the command? Excuse my anxiety but I do not want to make mistakes

Comment: Yes but but replace `adminusername` with your admin user name