# Getting error: "The account sign-in was incorrect or your account is disabled temporarily"

Tags: magento2, php

I create user by execute API call on: `"/index.php/rest/all/V1/customers"` with json body:

```
{
   "customer":{
      "id":0,
      "group_id":0,
      "email":"marcinwarzybok@outlook.com",
      "firstname":"Marcin",
      "lastname":"Warzybok"
   },
   "password":"Abcdef123"
}
```

Returns result:

```
{
   "id":2,
   "group_id":0,
   "created_at":"2020-09-08 11:58:13",
   "updated_at":"2020-09-08 11:58:13",
   "created_in":"Default Store View",
   "email":"marcinwarzybok@outlook.com",
   "firstname":"Marcin",
   "lastname":"Warzybok",
   "store_id":1,
   "website_id":1,
   "addresses":[
      
   ],
   "disable_auto_group_change":0,
   "extension_attributes":{
      "is_subscribed":false
   }
}
```

Which means i have a new user registered.
When i tried to login in by executing API call on `"/rest/all/V1/integration/customer/token"` with the following credentials in json body:
`{ "username":"marcinwarzybok@outlook.com", "password":"Abcdef123" }`
, it returns an error:

```
{
    "message": "The account sign-in was incorrect or your account is disabled temporarily. Please wait and try again later.",
    "trace": "#0 [internal function]: Magento\\Integration\\Model\\CustomerTokenService->createCustomerAccessToken('marcinwarzybok@...', 'Abcdef123')\n#1 /bitnami/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/SynchronousRequestProcessor.php(95): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#2 /bitnami/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(188): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\SynchronousRequestProcessor->process(Object(Magento\\Framework\\Webapi\\Rest\\Request\\Proxy))\n#3 /bitnami/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#4 /bitnami/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)\n#5 /bitnami/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#6 /bitnami/magento/htdocs/generated/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)\n#7 /bitnami/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(116): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#8 /bitnami/magento/htdocs/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch()\n#9 /bitnami/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(263): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->launch()\n#10 /bitnami/magento/htdocs/index.php(39): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor))\n#11 {main}"
}
```

But i should get some kind of token to make authorize calls. I found something like this: [your account is temporarily disabled](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/257672/your-account-is-temporarily-disabled). But i red this solution provide only temporary solution to a problem.

What about persistence resolve of a problem ? Is anyone have done working rest api integration in Magento 2?

Comment: This is for my own reference: I got same issue in postman and I was struggling to find the issue until I noticed PHPSession ID included in the header. I cleared all cookies and it worked again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make call on **/rest/default/V1/integration/customer/token** instead of on **/index.php/rest/default/V1/integration/customer/token**.

Second, make sure **you don't make call** to mapped subdomains. For example if you mapped *localhost* or *127.0.0.1* onto *mydomain.local* in /etc/hosts, don't make call to **http://mydomain.local/rest/default/V1/integration/customer/token**, but on **http://127.0.0.1/rest/default/V1/integration/customer/token**